# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused while using Selenium Java and webdriver (linux headless with Xvfb)

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, marionette, geckodriver

Recently i got a new virtual server which im trying to configure since some days to make my Java (8) based selenium web app running. This webapp is running inside a tomcat (8.5.31) and is using selenium for some basic website scraping. The OS of the server is gentoo (before i had a debian system which was running fine)

I spend already some days to make it work but now im stuck at the  following error:

```
1526203737341   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1526203737367   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:25016
1526203737796   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.ESuH8rdqpwT8"
1526203737802   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser
1526203739872   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 2828
1526203797867   webdriver::server       DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":""}}
11:29:57.944 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR test.Test - Exception occured while processing.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'gentoo', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.95-gentoo', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

This is what the process list is showing:

```
root      7808     1  0 14:36 ?        00:00:00   /usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1600x1200x24 -auth /etc/conf.d/Xvfb.cfg -listen tcp
tomcat    7863     1 59 14:38 ?        00:00:51   /etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderL
tomcat    7923  7863  0 14:38 ?        00:00:00     /opt/geckodriver --port=31399 -b /usr/bin/firefox-bin
tomcat    7943  7923  6 14:38 ?        00:00:04       /opt/firefox/firefox -marionette --headless -profile /tmp/rust_mozprofile.qpQfCj8DR1ab
tomcat    8032  7943  0 14:38 ?        00:00:00         /opt/firefox/plugin-container -greomni /opt/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /opt/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /opt/firefox/browser 7943 true tab
tomcat    7977     1  0 14:38 ?        00:00:00   dbus-launch --autolaunch 32b951aa6b930bec1f195b765af588f5 --binary-syntax --close-stderr
tomcat    7978     1  0 14:38 ?        00:00:00   /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
tomcat    7993     1  0 14:38 ?        00:00:00   /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
```

The Code for creating the Firefox instance (was using more detailed log levels to get some more informations about the problem):

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverGeckoPath);

    LoggingPreferences loggingPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
    loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.ALL);
    loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);
    loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
    loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.ALL);
    loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.ALL);

    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPrefs);

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(desiredCapabilities);
    options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);

    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

The geckodriver lays in /opt/ and is executable.

**My current setup/configuration**

**Selenium** 
All components are having version 3.12.0 (selenium-java, selenium-remote-driver, selenium-firefox-driver, selenium-api)

**Firefox** 
Version 60.0

**geckodriver** 
Version 20.1

**Xvfb configuration**

```
XVFB=/usr/bin/Xvfb
XVFBARGS=":99 -screen 0 1600x1200x24 -auth /etc/conf.d/Xvfb.cfg -nolisten tcp"
PIDFILE=/var/run/Xvfb.pid
```

**Xvfb config**

```
localhost
```

**Xvfb init.d-script**

```
start() {
        ebegin "Starting virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb"
        start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --background --exec $XVFB -- $XVFBARGS
        eend ${?}
}

stop() {
        ebegin  "Stopping virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb"
        start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE
        eend ${?}
}
```

**Export of display variable** (initialized at boot time for all users):

```
DISPLAY=:99
```

**/etc/conf.d/hostname**

```
gentoo
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       gentoo
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

Would appreciate very much any hints/tips to get more informations about how to debug/solve this problem...

## **Update 1**

I tried running my selenium component with the **`ChromeDriver` which interestingly works**. The code:

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/opt/chromedriver");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

The log shows:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 24646
Only local connections are allowed.
```

## **Update 2**

When im running the app in my local environment (similary configured / gentoo) everything works fine. But im not using Xvfb here but a xorg-server instead.
This is the logging output:

```
1526217622830   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1526217622833   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:12500
1526217622955   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.AZMw0iETRqFj"
1526217622955   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser
1526217623246   Marionette  DEBUG   Received observer notification profile-after-change
1526217623372   Marionette  DEBUG   Received observer notification command-line-startup
1526217623372   Marionette  DEBUG   Received observer notification nsPref:changed
1526217624744   Marionette  DEBUG   Received observer notification sessionstore-windows-restored
1526217624816   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref toolkit.cosmeticAnimations.enabled to false
1526217624816   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAccepted to false
1526217624816   Marionette  DEBUG   Setting recommended pref extensions.shield-recipe-client.api_url to 
1526217624847   Marionette  DEBUG   New connections are accepted
1526217624848   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 34253
1526217624860   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Connected to Marionette on localhost:34253
1526217624868   Marionette  DEBUG   Accepted connection 0 from 127.0.0.1:56070
```

For me it seems to be a connection problem between Marionette and the geckodriver. Could it be a port problem? On the server Marionette seems to listen always at port 2828, on my local machine its seems to be always a random port...

Answer (score 2):

For those whom it may concern I had the very same problem and got stuck in "connection refused" fiesta. After two whole night of try and error I found out that my previous processes of geckodriver, selenium and firefox was not closed and I had something around 50 open process. This three simple commands solved my problem

```
pkill geckodriver
pkill firefox
pkill selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
1526203737802   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser
1526203739872   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 2828
1526203797867   webdriver::server       DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":""}}
11:29:57.944 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR test.test.test.test.test.Test - Exception occured while processing.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
```

...implies that the GeckoDriver was unable to initiate/spawn a new Web Client session/instance successfully.

Your main issue is the way you have assigned the `DesiredCapabilities` type of object i.e. *desiredCapabilities* to the `FirefoxOptions` i.e to *options*. The proper way would be to pass the `DesiredCapabilities` class object i.e. *desiredCapabilities* through [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) function from [**`MutableCapabilities`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) class into the *FirefoxOptions* class object as follows : :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverGeckoPath);

LoggingPreferences loggingPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.ALL);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.ALL);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.ALL);

DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPrefs);

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.merge(desiredCapabilities);
options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

---

### Update

As you are still facing the same error consider performing the following steps :

- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Was redeploying the app with the changed code but still getting the same error message. I tried also to change Xvfb args from XVFBARGS=":99 -screen 0 1600x1200x24 -auth /etc/conf.d/Xvfb.cfg -nolisten tcp" just to "XVFBARGS=":99" but it also doesn't change anything. Do you have any more ideas what i could try? Can it be maybe somehow a host mapping problem? As im running a X server on my local machine im running out of ideas what else i could try on my server... :-(

Comment: @StephanM Check out my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: In the meanwhile i was trying to run my selenium component with a ChromeDriver: 
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/opt/chromedriver");
   driver = new ChromeDriver();`
which shows
`Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 24646
Only local connections are allowed.`
in the logs and **is working**.
Most of your suggested steps i can' t try as im using [gentoo](http://gentoo.org "gentoo"). As i wrote in my title its a webapp hosted in a tomcat. Its build with maven on my local machine and after transferred to my server.

Comment: DebanjanB: do you have any more ideas what i could try? Updated my post twice with new results/analysis...